# A population of bacteria can be modeled by the equation $P = 700[1-\frac{3}{(t^2+2)^2}]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Section 2.5 #15

A population of bacteria can be modeled by the equation:

$P = 700[1-\frac{3}{(t^2+2)^2}]$

Find the rate of change with respect to $t$ when $t=1$

---

So we have to take the derivative with respect to $t$ and then plug in $1$.

$\frac{dP}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}700[1-\frac{3}{(t^2+2)^2}]$

$\frac{dP}{dt} = 700[\frac{d}{dt}1-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{3}{(t^2+2)^2}]$

$\frac{dP}{dt} = 700[0-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{3}{(t^2+2)^2}]$

$\frac{dP}{dt} = 700[-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{3}{(t^2+2)^2}]$

Okay, so here is the hard part, trying to evaluate $-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{3}{(t^2+2)^2}$. Let's use the properties of exponents to move the denominator up into numerator and then use the chain rule.

$\frac{dP}{dt} = 700[-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{3}{(t^2+2)^2}]$

$\frac{dP}{dt} = 700[-\frac{d}{dt}3(t^2+2)^{-2}]$

The $3$ is just a constant so we don't have to worry about it while taking the derivative, and so

$\frac{dP}{dt} = 700[-3\frac{d}{dt}(t^2+2)^{-2}]$

$\frac{dP}{dt} = 700[-3\frac{d}{dt}(t^2+2)^{-2}]$

$\frac{dP}{dt} = 700[-3(-2)(t^2+2)^{-3}\frac{d}{dt}(t^2+2)]$

$\frac{dP}{dt} = 700[6(t^2+2)^{-3}\frac{d}{dt}(t^2+2)]$

$\frac{dP}{dt} = 700[6(t^2+2)^{-3}2t$

$\frac{dP}{dt} = 8400t(t^2+2)^{-3}$

$\frac{dP}{dt} = \frac{8400t}{(t^2+2)^{3}}$

Now we plug in $t=1$ and get:

$\frac{8400(1)}{(1^2+2)^{3}}=311.11111 \approx 311.1$

If we wanted to plug in $t=2$ then:

$\frac{8400(2)}{(2^2+2)^{3}}=77.7777777 \approx 77.8$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I'm not seeing the question. If you're asking whether or not you've differentiated the function correctly, then I would answer "yes". Are you, in general,  having difficulty applying the chain rule?

Comment: @solidstatejake look at the tags (solution-verification)

Comment: Got it. I've not seen that before. Thanks. @an4s